# React js how we can set Stripe test secret key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

While doing card charging,In nodejs we are using this method

> "var stripe = require("stripe")('STRIPE SECRET KEY');"

and after that we use that variable and charge the card.
I want to get the same thing in React js how we can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't / shouldn't need to use your secret key in a client side app.

You should use your publishable key client side, which will be used to generate a token.
The token can be passed back to your server to do the actual processing.

See here for a complete guide.
https://davidwalsh.name/step-step-guide-stripe-payments-react